# Looker - How to have 1 dashboard filter for Name that will dynamically change multiple visuals that have a different Name column?

Tags: join, filter, dashboard, looker, lookml

In Looker I have a dashboard that shows details about Tickets.

The 1st visual shows the NAME of the user who Opened the ticket and a count, then there is a 2nd visual showing the NAME of the user who is currently assigned the ticket and a count, and finally there is a 3rd visual showing the NAME of the user who closed the ticket and a count.

With these 3 visuals, the column/field for each NAME is in a different LookML view.

What I want to achieve, is have 1 dashboard filter to select a NAME that will filter all 3 visuals. But because each NAME field is in its separate LookML view - it is problematic choosing 1 of these 3. For instance, if I choose to use the NAME for who Opened the ticket as my dashboard filter, just because the NAME I select in my dashboard filter opened the ticket does not mean they are currently assigned or closed the ticket - meaning this filter would ONLY be useful for the visual showing who Opened the ticket and a count.

I want 1 filter that will dynamically filter all 3 visuals showing just 1 name and the same name which is provided in that dashboard filter.

Table Data:

- OpenedByTable -id, name
- AssignedTable -id, name
- ClosedTable -id, name

I am able to re-use a 'user' LookML view in case I need a 4th LookML view. Perhaps this 4th view could be used to join the above 3 onto?Then I use this desired/new column from the 4th LookML view

[image: Current Dashboard example]

[image: What I am hoping I can achieve]

[image: Current issue]

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter that the name fields are in different views. When creating a filter, the view you are pointing is just used to populate the filter alternatives.

Let's say you have a filter based on `OpenedByTable.Name`. When you click on the filter Looker will issue a query something like this to generate the alternatives:

```sql
SELECT Name 
FROM OpenedByTable.Name
GROUP BY 1
```

If one of the alternatives is `Karl` and you select that, looker will then issue a query like this to `AssignedTable`.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM AssignedTable
WHERE AssignedTable.Name IN ('Karl')
```

I guess your explore looks something like this:

```
explore: tickets {}

view: tickets {
  derived_table: {
    sql:
      SELECT 'A' AS ticket_id, 'Mike' AS opened_by, 'Carl' AS closed_by
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'B' AS ticket_id, 'Mike' AS opened_by, 'Mike' AS closed_by
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'C' AS ticket_id, 'Carl' AS opened_by, 'Carl' AS closed_by
    ;;
  }

  dimension: ticket_id {}
  dimension: opened_by {}
  dimension: closed_by {}

  measure: count_tickets {
    type: count_distinct
    sql: ${ticket_id} ;;
  }

}
```

You can then build a `.lookml`-dashboard like this to have one visual for closed and one for opened, with a single name filter to control both.

```yaml
- dashboard: tickets
  title: tickets
  layout: newspaper
  preferred_viewer: dashboards-next

  filters:
  - name: name
    type: field_filter
    ui_config:
      type: button_group
      display: inline
    explore: tickets
    # just to populate the filter, if there are people who have not closed tickets
    # but have opened, you should build a name/dimension-explore 
    field: tickets.closed_by 
  
  elements:
  - title: Closed
    name: Closed
    explore: tickets
    type: table
    fields: [tickets.closed_by, tickets.count_tickets]
    listen:
      name: tickets.closed_by # filter the opened_by field with whatever name you have selected in the filter
    row: 0
    col: 0
    width: 3
    height: 3
  
  - title: Opened
    name: Opened
    explore: tickets
    type: table
    fields: [tickets.count_tickets, tickets.opened_by]
    listen:
      name: tickets.opened_by # filter the opened_by field with whatever name you have selected in the filter
    row: 0
    col: 3
    width: 3
    height: 3
```

Or if you build dashboards visually set the filter like this:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately no this is not how it is working. If you and I are in a team of two, and both me and you can create tickets but only I can close them, if I filter the OpenedBy.Name to 'Karl' it is still showing my name under the ClosedBy when it should only show yours (if you had closed any tickets)

Comment: I have a tickets table, and it is 1 row per ticket. On that row, is a CreatedByID, AssignedByID and ClosedByID. Filtering on one of those only will show and pull through the other data on that row(s)

Comment: I'm not really following. Could you update your question with example data and expected result?

Comment: I have added screenshots of example data.